# Using Backspace while or after entered the text in uitextfield showing text length wrong

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Here l1,l2,l3,l4 are `UILabel`s.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"%d",textField.text.length);

     if (textField.text.length==0)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@"__";
        l3.text=@"__";
        l4.text=@"__";
    }else if (textField.text.length==1)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@".";
        l3.text=@"__";
        l4.text=@"__";
    }else if (textField.text.length==2)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@".";
        l3.text=@".";
        l4.text=@"__";
    }else if (textField.text.length==3)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@".";
        l3.text=@".";
        l4.text=@".";
    }
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 4) ? NO : YES;

}
```

Here output follows as...

textfield is 1234 then labels are . . . .

it's working fine but when the user deletes characters from the text field, I get the following results:

"123" . . . .
"12"  . . . .
"1"   . . . _
""    . . _ _

What I expect is that when the textfield contains no characters, my labels would show _ _ _ _

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make any sense, please re-word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the text that **results** from the user editing that field.  To do so create a new string:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *editedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"%d",editedText.length);

    if (editedText.length==0)
    {
        l1.text=@"__";
        l2.text=@"__";
        l3.text=@"__";
        l4.text=@"__";
    }
    else if (editedText.length==1)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@"__";
        l3.text=@"__";
        l4.text=@"__";
    }else if (editedText.length==2)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@".";
        l3.text=@"__";
        l4.text=@"__";
    }else if (editedText.length==3)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@".";
        l3.text=@".";
        l4.text=@"__";
    }else if (editedText.length==4)
    {
        l1.text=@".";
        l2.text=@".";
        l3.text=@".";
        l4.text=@".";
    }
    return (editedText.length > 4) ? NO : YES;

}
```

Comment: Once you make that change to the text handling you need to change the logic of the `if ` statements (1, 2, 3, 4)...

Comment: I got the answer what i want..thank you Jonathan and A'sa Dickens

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextField` does not update it's text until the end of that function if you return YES. Your assuming that the textField.text is updated to reflect what you hit before that function. What you need to do is test the `string` parameter and see if it is a `backspace` character code. If it is then you should be testing for textField.text.length - 1 .

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSInteger offSet = 0;
    if ( [string isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        offset = 1;
    }

    if ( textField.text.length - offSet == value ) {

    }

    BOOL shouldChangeCharacters = YES;
    return shouldChangeCharacters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should base your `if` statements on the actual text that will be in the text field after the edit is approved and actioned. By using `if (textField.text.length==0)` you are assuming that you start with nothing and add a character to get to a single character in the text field - this is not a valid assumption.

Use The current text in the `textField` together with the `range` and `replacementString` to get the actual resulting text (`stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:`).

Note that this will also allow you to deal with users cutting and pasting text into the field.

Comment: I did not think of it like this way XD, for some weird reason :p , but now when i use this function i will remember that thought process, even though I usually do that... just never thought about it.